# Couldn't find id=:all - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
<ul id = "subjects">
   <% Subject.find(:all).each do |c| %>
   <li><%= link_to c.name, :action => "show_subjects", :id => c.id %></li>
   <% end %>
</ul>
```

I have a code snippet in my list.html.erb file. It raises an exception 'Couldn't find Subject with 'id'=all'. What's the problem in this case? The thing I want to do is to list all subjects as the hyperlinks.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is you're using code that is ancient.
Replace it with either of those two.

```
Subject.all.each do ...
```

or

```
Subject.find_each do ...
```

Explanation for error is that `find` automatically searches by id and `:all` is not a valid `id` and so it can't find anything and raises an exception.