# ruby/rails displaying database on index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've looked at all the other question on here and none seem to fully answer my question, as one solution ends up causeing another error somewhere else in my project.

I am trying to display all "Promotions" from the promotions database on the index view but I keep running into errors, my current error is that in my home controller its saying that "Couldn't find Promotion with 'id'=all".

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Home Controler**

```
    class HomeController < ApplicationController
      def index
        @Promotion = Promotion.find :all
      end
```

**Model**

```
  class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.abstract_class = true
    self.primary_key= :promo_id
  end
```

**View**

```
    <%= @promotions.promo_id %>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43967269/couldnt-find-id-all-ruby-on-rails/43967315#43967315

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show all your `Promotion`, do something like

```
def index
  @promotions = Promotion.all
end
```

And in your view:

```
<% @promotions.each do |promotion| %>
    <%= promotion.id %>
    <%= promotion.name %>
<% end %>
```